# Python - Extract text from mulitple strings from multiple files

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python guru, I need to extract all the text from List till URL, below is the sample of the pattern. I also want the script able to loop all the files in the folders.

```
 .....
 .....
 <List>Product Line</List>
 <URL>http://teamspace.abb.com/sites/Product</URL>
 ...
 ...
 <List>Contact Number</List>
 <URL>https://teamspace.abb.com/sites/Contact</URL>
 ....
 ....
```

Expected output

```
<List>Product Line</List>
<URL>http://teamspace.abb.com/sites/Product</URL>
<List>Contact Number</List>
<URL>https://teamspace.abb.com/sites/Contact</URL>
```

I've developed a script which able to loop all the files in a folders and then extract all key word that start from List, but I unable to include URL. Your help is much appreciated.

```
# defining location of parent folder
  BASE_DIRECTORY = 'C:\D_Drive\Projects\Test'
  output_file = open('C:\D_Drive\Projects\\Test\Output.txt', 'w')
  output = {}
  file_list = []

# scanning through sub folders
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(BASE_DIRECTORY):
for f in filenames:
    if 'xml' in str(f):
        e = os.path.join(str(dirpath), str(f))
        file_list.append(e)

for f in file_list:
print f
txtfile = open(f, 'r')
output[f] = []
for line in txtfile:
    if '<List>' in line:
        output[f].append(line)
tabs = []
for tab in output:
tabs.append(tab)

tabs.sort()
for tab in tabs:
output_file.write(tab + '\n')
output_file.write('\n')
for row in output[tab]:
    output_file.write(row + '')
output_file.write('\n')
output_file.write('----------------------------------------------------------\n')

raw_input()
```

[Sample file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s2revjasu3nyr3e/Product_Workflow.xml?dl=0)

Comment: input and expected output look the same. try to improve your question

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Just use a xml parser, such as [xml tree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Comment: please update the indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is mostly right the only change needed it to create an iterator for the file.  You could use element tree or beautiful soup but understanding iteration like this will also work when it's a non xml or html file.

```
txtfile = iter(open(f, 'r'))  # change here
output[f] = []
for line in txtfile:
    if '<List>' in line:
        output[f].append(line)
        output[f].append(next(txtfile))  # and here
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Try with [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('Product_Workflow.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
with open('Output.txt','w') as opfile:
    for l,u in zip(root.iter('List'),root.iter('URL')):
        opfile.write(ET.tostring(l).strip())
        opfile.write('\n')
        opfile.write(ET.tostring(u).strip())
        opfile.write('\n')
```

The `Output.txt` will give you:

```
<List>Emove</List>
<URL>http://teamspace.abb.com/sites/Product</URL>
<List>Asset_KWT</List>
<URL>https://teamspace.slb.com/sites/Contact</URL>
```

Comment: Thanks  for the information. I will look at xml element method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` or a list comprehension like so:

```
tgt=('URL', 'List')
with open('file') as f:  
    print filter(lambda line: any(e in line for e in tgt), (line for line in f))
```

Or:

```
with open('/tmp/file') as f:  
    print [line for line in f if any(e in line for e in tgt)]
```

Either prints:

```
[' <List>Product Line</List>\n', ' <URL>http://teamspace.abb.com/sites/Product</URL>\n', ' <List>Contact Number</List>\n', ' <URL>https://teamspace.abb.com/sites/Contact</URL>\n']
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will look at it.